# Laravel Routing with Ajax back to iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have routing issue with laravel when calling ajax within a iframe but I don't really understand what could be causing it since what I have should call ajax and return successfully. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried using  return Response::json( $response ); , and a whole bunch of different things but to no avail. I still have this 500 error. I ran composer dump-autoload as well. Any help and explanation as to why this is failing would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseLocalUrl, //baseLocalUrl= "http://localhost:4567/admin/menuBuilder/1/save"
            data: 
            {
                html: $("#menuHTML").text()
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert("success!");
            }


});
```

Here is my route

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
.....
Route::post('menuBuilder/{role}/save' , array('uses' => 'AdminMenuBuilderController@saveHTML' ));
.....
});
```

Here is my controller method

```
public function saveHTML($roleId){
      return Response::json(array('status' => 'OK'));

}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
 POST http://localhost:4567/admin/menuBuilder/1/save 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Laravel Log:

```
production.ERROR: 500 - Exception @ /admin/menuBuilder/1/save
exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /vagrant/app/filters.php:98
```

filters.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application & Route Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Below you will find the "before" and "after" events for the application
| which may be used to do any work before or after a request into your
| application. Here you may also register your custom route filters.
|
*/

App::before(function($request)
{
    //
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    //
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following filters are used to verify that the user of the current
| session is logged into this application. The "basic" filter easily
| integrates HTTP Basic authentication for quick, simple checking.
|
*/

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if ( Auth::guest() ) // If the user is not logged in
    {
            return Redirect::guest('user/login');
    }
});

Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Guest Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The "guest" filter is the counterpart of the authentication filters as
| it simply checks that the current user is not logged in. A redirect
| response will be issued if they are, which you may freely change.
|
*/

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('user/login/');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Role Permissions
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Access filters based on roles.
|
*/

// Check for role on all admin routes
Entrust::routeNeedsRole( 'admin*', array('admin'), Redirect::to('/') );

// Check for permissions on admin actions
Entrust::routeNeedsPermission( 'admin/blogs*', 'manage_blogs', Redirect::to('/admin') );
Entrust::routeNeedsPermission( 'admin/comments*', 'manage_comments', Redirect::to('/admin') );
Entrust::routeNeedsPermission( 'admin/users*', 'manage_users', Redirect::to('/admin') );
Entrust::routeNeedsPermission( 'admin/roles*', 'manage_roles', Redirect::to('/admin') );

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CSRF Protection Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The CSRF filter is responsible for protecting your application against
| cross-site request forgery attacks. If this special token in a user
| session does not match the one given in this request, we'll bail.
|
*/

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::getToken() != Input::get('csrf_token') &&  Session::getToken() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Language
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Detect the browser language.
|
*/

Route::filter('detectLang',  function($route, $request, $lang = 'auto')
{

    if($lang != "auto" && in_array($lang , Config::get('app.available_language')))
    {
        Config::set('app.locale', $lang);
    }else{
        $browser_lang = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? strtok(strip_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']), ',') : '';
        $browser_lang = substr($browser_lang, 0,2);
        $userLang = (in_array($browser_lang, Config::get('app.available_language'))) ? $browser_lang : Config::get('app.locale');
        Config::set('app.locale', $userLang);
        App::setLocale($userLang);
    }
});
```

Comment: are you forget `csrf` token about?

Comment: I am not familiar with the csrf token. Please explain and evaluate.

Comment: take a look to your `csrf` filter, it wait your input has `csrf_token` or `_key` key with token.

Comment: Yes. You are right that is the problem. I commented it out and I get a successful return. Now how would I go about generating a csrf token from the site. From what I am reading here http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html I need to render the csrf token when I create the page. Is this the only way to get around this?

Comment: try to read my answer. hope, it helps.

Comment: Laravel already made all this work for you - your page has `<meta name="token" content="Some_Token" />` all, that you need, pass it while ajax.

Comment: Hm, and what's wrong with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473924/ajax-with-laravel-error-with-routing ?

Comment: Same thing. I tried different things but I think I am going to delete that one since at this point I realize its a repeat question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to your csrf filter, it wait your input has `csrf_token` or `_token` key with token.

I suggest to provide it as a header while doing `ajax` requests:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('x-csrf-token') : (Input::get('csrf_token') ?: Input::get('_token'));

    if (Session::token() != $token)
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

And client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    datatype: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='token']").attr('content'));
    },
})
```