# Asynchronous rating (like/dislike) with laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, asynchronous

I'm implementing a like/dislike feature using laravel. I got everything up and running except for the asynchronous request. I only want logged in users to be able to like/dislike an item so the request has to be verified server side. I also want it to be an asynchronous request, so no page refresh.

What would be a good way to do this? I already have jquery loaded so using angular JUST for that would be a bit of an overkill. How would I protect the request? I have read things about tokens, but I'm not quite sure about that.

Comment: I have not used laravel before so I am not entirely sure but is there something that is stopping you from making an asynchronous ajax request?

Comment: Security is stopping me. I don't want people to make thousands of requests to the database to pump up the likes for something. So I need a way to protect the `Route`. I'm reading up on sending CSRF tokens in the header during the ajax request. I'm just curious what other people have to say about this and whether the method i'm reading right now is a good approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to add a csrf filter to your config.php file. Laravel should generate csrf values for you by default but if not you can use it the following way with blade.

```
{{ csrf_token() }}
```

Your ajax could look something like this below. Note the csrf token could also be in your header tag as well but I put it here because of the way my code worked.

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
              return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',"{{ csrf_token() }}");
            },
            url: baseLocalUrl, //this would be your path to your route
            data: 
            {
                html: sendHTML //data separated by a comma
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert("Success");
              },
              error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                alert('Failed');
              }


});
```

For me on my last project, I have a bunch of forms and some ajax with csrf so I had to change the config filter to this because I had trouble mending the two so I created the following filter below.

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('x-csrf-token') : (Input::get('csrf_token') ?: Input::get('_token'));
    $test1 = Session::getToken() != Input::get('csrf_token') &&  Session::getToken() != Input::get('_token');
    $test2 = Session::token() != $token;

    if($test2 && $test1){

         throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473924/ajax-with-laravel-error-with-routing) with more details