# laravel 5.2 ajax controller switch language internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i'm trying to create a ajax controller to switch locate, here are the code:

frontend jquery :

```
<script language="javascript">
$( "#lang" )
  .change(function () {
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "{{ url('/lang') }}",
          headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
          data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
        })
          .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
  })
</script>
```

controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LangController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function Lang () {

        /*$rules = [
            'language' => 'in:en,zh-tw' //list of supported languages of your application.
        ];*/

        App::setLocale('zh-tw');

        return 'success';
    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::post('lang', 'LangController@lang');
```

The result is internal server error 500, the App::setLocale('zh-tw'); run well in other non-ajax controller, everyone know what's wrong with that?

Comment: You can check the logs folder and/or apache2 log to see what actually the error is.

Comment: i use xampp on windows, but the error log didn't log that.

Comment: Well generally internal server error is a `5XX level error` - generally occurs at server level. So it should have been logged - either in `apache` or in `application`. However - you can enable `E_ALL` in `php.ini` error setting cause without checking what the error is - it's hard to solve.

Comment: BTW, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27474251/926943 seems similar to your problem. You can check that too.

Comment: i found this in chrome console Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App' not found

Comment: okay in that case you need to use `\App:setLocale()` instead of `App:setLocale()`. The difference is the `backslash` before - which denotes this App is in `global namespace` outside the namespace of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `\App::setLocale('zh-tw');`

because you want to use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class`
but compiler is looking for `App` class in current namespace. you can also import the class by using `use App` alias. more on namespace [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: the error is gone, but language switching is not work.

Comment: try following the docs exactly, i.e return `trans('messages.welcome')` instead of `'success'` . https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization